# Laravel abandoned dependency issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dependencies

So I just took over a laravel 5.2 based project with some [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell).

The backend is build on a **smarch/watchtower** package which has been abandoned and laravel 5.3 is the highest version it supports.
**tsawler/laravel-filemanager**  is one more abandoned package.

Now I would like to update the whole project to the latest version of laravel to enjoy the new features, bug fixes and security patches and add the possibility to use other packages.

**What are the best practices in such a situation?**

1. Should I go with hijacking the abandoned packages one at a time and update them,
2. find similar packages with strong community support and replace the abandoned ones,
3. build the whole project from the start on a fresh copy of laravel 6
4. or accept the truth and continue on the old version?

any other suggestions?

Links to abandoned packages:

[smarch/watchtower](https://packagist.org/packages/smarch/watchtower)

[tsawler/laravel-filemanager](https://packagist.org/packages/tsawler/laravel-filemanager)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I use packages from vendors that I know will be kept updated (such as Spatie packages). In place of Watchtower, you could use [laravel-permission] https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission. However, tsawler/laravel-filemanager did install on Laravel v6.x. Though it says use https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager so I'd install that instead.

From there you can upgrade from 5.2 to 6.x yourself or have a service like [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com/) do it for you. I create a new laravel instance and diff the directories to see what files changed. Also, make sure you read the upgrade guide: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade. This might help as well: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-52-to-6?page=1